# Firebase setValue not creating unique child node?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    ArrayList<ListingModel> list = new ArrayList<ListingModel>();
    list.add(model);
    list.add(model2);
    list.add(model3);
    list.add(model4);

    for (ListingModel m : list) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("node");
        myRef.push().setValue(m);

    }
```

I am trying to save 4 objects from android app to firebase database. So I am using loop to store data into the node. It should have create 4 different child with auto id and stored the object there . But it's only storing the last model in one unique id like image below :
[image]

How can I save all four objects(data in list)  with unique id each?

Comment: keep initialising reference outside loop: 

   ` FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("node");
    for (ListingModel m : list) {
           myRef.push().setValue(m);
        }`

Comment: Same result even if I instiantiate reference outside the loop. @JerinAMathews

Comment: Add a `CompletionListener` to `setValue()` to see if any writes are failing.  Do you have security rules on the children of `node` that might be rejecting the first three models?  I run your code and can't reproduce your results.

Comment: Yes @BobSnyder there is no error in above code. My bad. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Fully documented at firebase

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
// Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
// /posts/$postid simultaneously
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Put your models in a map, put them, and use `updateChildren`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is to use for loop.

```
    ArrayList<ListingModel> list = new ArrayList<ListingModel>();
    list.add(model);
    list.add(model2);
    list.add(model3);
    list.add(model4);

    for (int i =0; i<list.size();i++){
        ListingModel model = list.get(i); 
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("node"); 
        myRef.child(i).setValue(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with how I set the model (Sorry for partial code in my question)

```
    ListingModel model = new ListingModel();
    model.setTitle("test0");

    ListingModel model1 = new ListingModel();
    model.setTitle("test1");

    ListingModel model2 = new ListingModel();
    model.setTitle("test2");

    ListingModel model3 = new ListingModel();
    model.setTitle("test3");
```

I was instantiating different models, but only altering value of first **model**.

*model1, model2, and model3* was empty hence was not appearing in firebase database for being an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code only read push once. And when you using the same id to write the data, you will overwrite the previous version.

```
ArrayList<ListingModel> list = new ArrayList<ListingModel>();
list.add(model);
list.add(model2);
list.add(model3);
list.add(model4);

for (ListingModel m : list) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("node");
    String modelID = myRef.push().getKey();
    myRef.child(modelID).setValue(m);
}
```

Try this, I hope it helps.

Btw, practice using updateChildren rather than setValue for saving your data.